# How to show particular number of results in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having grid which will show 8 inches width and 12 inches height in a loop. How to remove the last result in a loop example 2,4,6,8 will print. i need to remove 8(dynamic value) in the loop.

For example i am directly using 8 as value here.

```
    var rowInch ='';
    var count=0;
     for(var row = 0; row<=8;row++) {
        if(count%2 === 0) {
        rowInch = count;
       }

   \\show only 2,4,6

   }
```

Comment: If you don't want 8, use `row < 8` instead of `row <= 8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want last even number from dynamic number of rows you can use as below , now even if numbers of rows are 9 , you will get 2,4,6

```js
var rowInch ='';
    var count=0;
    var numRows=9;
     for(var row = 1; row<=numRows;row++) {
    
      if(numRows-1>row)  
      if(row%2 === 0) {
       console.log(row)
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to omit last value, replace `row<=8` with `row<8`

```js
var rowInch=0;
var count=8;
 for(var row = 1;row<count;row++) {
    if(row%2 === 0) {
      rowInch = row;
      console.log(rowInch);
   }

 }
```